# JavaScript copy properties by reference without modifying the original object

Tags: javascript, object

I have objects A and B and would like pass properties of A into B by reference, without passing B's props into A. I.e.:

```
const A = { d: 1, e: 2 };
const B = { f: 10, g: 20 };
const C = Object.assign(A, B);

A.d = 10;

console.log(C); // { d: 10, e: 2, f: 10, g: 20} as desired
console.log(A); // { d: 10, e: 2, f: 10, g: 20} but would like just { d: 10, e: 2 }
```

Is there a way to do this, without using functions/getters to copy things?

Comment: Do you want to allow setting values in `C`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: Notice that `C === A` because that's how `Object.assign` works. If you want a separate copy, create a new object, with `C = Object.assign({}, A, B)` or `C = {...A, ...B}`.

Comment: *'without using functions/getters to copy things'* no, primitive values are not copied by reference so you need an active method of propagating the change. If you set the values as objects then yes. Also if you want the properties of`A` in `B` then you should reverse the order you are passing them to `Object.assign`.

Comment: Right, thanks, that makes sense, `Object.assign()` returns reference to the original (modified) object but the primitive properties are not copied by reference, the object is.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to create a view over the objects `A` and `B`.

```js
const A = { d: 1, e: 2 };
const B = { f: 10, g: 20 };
const C = new Proxy({}, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    return Object.hasOwn(B, prop) ? B[prop] : A[prop];
  },
  ownKeys() {
    return [...new Set(Object.keys(A).concat(Object.keys(B)))];
  },
  getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, prop) {
    return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.hasOwn(B, prop) ? B : A, prop);
  }
});

A.d = 10;

console.log(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(C))); // { d: 10, e: 2, f: 10, g: 20}
console.log(A); // { d: 10, e: 2 }
```

Comment: This is assuming you do not allow modifying any properties using `C`.

Answer (score 0):

You could take an empty object as target. This does not mutate given objects.

```js
const
    a = { d: 1, e: 2 },
    b = { f: 10, g: 20 },
    c = Object.assign({}, a, b);

a.d = 10;

console.log(c); // { d: 10, e: 2, f: 10, g: 20 }
console.log(a); // { d: 10, e: 2 }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I don't know why you rate this answer when it's wrong. c will be "{ d: 1, e: 2, f: 10, g: 20 }" and won't get d value updated when doing a.d = 10

Comment: @AntonHoncharuk, `a` is changing, `c` is not. what else do you get?

Comment: The expected output for `c` is `{ d: 10, e: 2, f: 10, g: 20 }`, but your code outputs `d: 1`.

Comment: @all, right, i see it as error of op. this approach takes two objects and merge this and does not change the source objects. `a.c` changes only `a`.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't really work for me, I don't want to copy the properties but instead have a pointer to the properties of the source object, without adding target object's properties to the source.

Comment: what does it look like?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use the spread operator to copy the properties of object A into a new object, and then use Object.assign to merge that new object with object B. This will create a new object with the properties of A and B, without modifying either of the original objects. Here's an example:

```
const A = { d: 1, e: 2 };
const B = { f: 10, g: 20 };
const C = Object.assign({...A}, B);

A.d = 10;

console.log(C); // { d: 1, e: 2, f: 10, g: 20} as desired
console.log(A); // { d: 10, e: 2 } as desired
```